# Z index in bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, overlay, z-index, carousel

Hi I am having an element as the direct child of body which acts as a overlay(black) with fixed positioning and z-index as 99. Also I am having a text field in bootstrap carousel which again will be shown on clicking it before the black overlay.

But the thing is I am getting the text field behind the black overlay as carousel's item has lower z index the text field inside it also gets lower. Any answers will be helpful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616587/is-it-possible-to-have-a-child-element-behind-his-parent-element-with-z-index

Comment: Showing some code would make things easier